# Conflicting Background color and minted style

Tags: minted

I am trying to use minted to show a bnf code and I want a dark or black background. However the code scheme for the bnf is conflicting with the style so some text do not appear. How can I modify the color scheme for bnf using minted. My latex code is shown below.

```
%% Requires compilation with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{minted}[fontsize=\scriptsize, style=vim, bgcolor=black]{bnf}
<postal-address> ::= <name-part> <street-address> some text some text some text <zip-part>
      <name-part> ::= <personal-part> <last-name> <opt-suffix-part> <EOL> | <personal-part> <name-part>
  <personal-part> ::= <initial> "." | <first-name> | terminal 1
 <street-address> ::= <house-num> <street-name> <opt-apt-num> <EOL>
       <zip-part> ::= <town-name> "," <state-code> <ZIP-code> <EOL>
<opt-suffix-part> ::= "Sr." | "Jr." | <roman-numeral> | ""
    <opt-apt-num> ::= <apt-num> | ""
\end{minted}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```